# Manage docker containers through NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a game with its backend, and I wanted for players to be able to start servers, custom or just join one official,I wanted to deploy those servers in a vm using docker.
I already have a docker-compose and an image setted up but I'm having issues starting it.
I made already a nodejs app that chooses a service from the docker-compose that isnt "up" already, but I'm having issues starting it.
If I run the commands by themselfs in the console I can already start the server and connect to it.

Tried running cmd commands directly on the app, dockerode also doesnt seem to have any function to start services, I also havent found a language that can make this problem easier to solve.
I've looked into swarms but I think I would run into the same problem.
I know the best way to do this would be with kubernets, but kubernets has a big learning curve and I dont have much time, and I'm not even sure it will do what I want.

I wanted a way where my app recieves a http request runs "docker compose up game_server1 -d", and know wether or not the server started successfullyy, and be able to shut it down.

If there is a better way to initiate game servers has I need I'm also open to suggestions.
This is what I have so far:

```
var Docker = require('dockerode');
const fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const path = require('path');

//! PORT RANGE 27000-27100
const docker = new Docker({ socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock' }); 

const composeFilePath = './docker/docker-compose.yml';
const fullcomposeFilePath = '~/Slave_js/docker/docker-compose.yml';


var services = [];
try {
    const yamlData = fs.readFileSync(composeFilePath, 'utf8');
    const serviceobj = yaml.load(yamlData).services;
    services = Object.keys(serviceobj).map((serviceName) => ({
        name: serviceName,
        config: serviceobj[serviceName],
      }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error parsing YAML:', error);
  }


class Game {
    static async start_game(id) {
        try {
            let tempServices = services;
            let containers = await docker.listContainers({ all: true });
            for(let container of containers){
                for(let i = 0; i<tempServices.length;i++){
                    let service = tempServices[i];
                    let name = container.Image;
                    name = name.split("-")[1];
                    if(name == service.name){
                        tempServices.splice(i,1);
                        break;
                    }    
                               
                }
            }
            if(!tempServices.length)
                return{status: 507, result: {msg:"Server full"}}
            let service = tempServices[0];
            //up the service
            //return true with the port 
            return{status: 200, result: {msg:"Started Successfully"}}
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return { status: 500, result: { msg: "Internal server error" }};
        }  
    }

}
module.exports = Game;
```

Comment: What's the more specific problem you're running into?  Do you get any sort of error message or other output?  How do you ensure these servers will stop; what will you do if you get a sudden burst of thousands of requests to create servers?  (Can you have a single long-running server process that you share among the clients instead?)

Comment: I just solved the problem when creating the containers. The way I was thinking of stoping the server is that the game server it self when it saw there were no players online, would send a request to the server controlling the docker and it would turn off. About the thousand of requests, I already have a master server that manages that, but it wouldnt be able to withstand thousands, for now has this is a uni project I limited the max amount of server to 10 per each vm.